# When is ISomeGenericInterface<T> assignable to ISomeGenericInterface<T>?

Tags: delphi, generics, delphi-2010

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Generic method returning generic interface in Delphi 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574358/generic-method-returning-generic-interface-in-delphi-2010)

In Delphi 2010, when is `ISomeGenericInterface<T>` assignable to `ISomeGenericInterface<T>`?

The following program compiles and runs as expected ...

```
unit uGenDemo;
interface

{.$define declare-a-type}

function Tokenize: IEnumerator<string>;
{$IFDEF declare-a-type}
type TX = integer;
{$ENDIF}

implementation  

uses SysUtils;

type
IStringEnumerator = interface( IEnumerator<string>)
    ['{3A28E4FB-CDF7-4933-8D67-D9EF5C2466E0}']
  end;

TBaseEnumerator = class( TInterfacedObject, IEnumerator)
  private
    function  MoveNext: Boolean;
    function  BaseGetCurrent: TObject;
    function  IEnumerator.GetCurrent = BaseGetCurrent;
    procedure Reset;
  end;

TStringEnumerator = class( TBaseEnumerator, IStringEnumerator)
  private
    function GetCurrent: string;
    property Current: string read GetCurrent;
  end;

function Tokenize: IEnumerator<string>;
begin
result := TStringEnumerator.Create as IStringEnumerator
end;


{ TBaseEnumerator }

function TBaseEnumerator.BaseGetCurrent: TObject;
begin
result := nil
end;

function TBaseEnumerator.MoveNext: Boolean;
begin
result := False
end;

procedure TBaseEnumerator.Reset;
begin
end;

{ TStringEnumerator }

function TStringEnumerator.GetCurrent: string;
begin
result := ''
end;


end.
```

... however when we declare any type after declaring the `Tokenize()` function, for example, by changing the line from...

```
{.$define declare-a-type}
```

... to ...

```
{$define declare-a-type}
```

... the compiler baulks and throws error ...

```
[DCC Error] uGenDemo.pas(43): E2010 Incompatible types: 'IEnumerator<System.string>' and 'IStringEnumerator'
```

**Why?**

1. Is this a compiler bug?
2. In general is it safe to assign an interface pointer to an interface pointer of an ancestor type which is generically parameterized?

(My compiler version is Embarcadero® Delphi® 2010 Version 14.0.3593.25826)

Comment: Actually, I see this question has already been answered (more or less)  here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574358/generic-method-returning-generic-interface-in-delphi-2010

Comment: Voting to close my own question.

Comment: Shouldn't you delete the question? It has no answers so it's in your power to simply delete it.